# Tropical Operation Conversions: Multiple Operations

Tags: functions, replacement, polynomials, algebra

I apologize if my syntax is bad. I looked around, but didn't see anything on this in the stack exchange.

I would like to be able to transform a classical real-valued polynomial to a tropical polynomial. The rule set that we're using are:
"a+b"=max(a,b), "a+b+c+..."=max(a,b,c,...)
"a*b"=a+b, "a*b*c*..."=a+b+c+...

I've defined those operations in the code below, but the problem I'm running into is that I can't convince Mathematica to take more than 2 expressions and separate it into separate terms as I would like. Here's my definitions:

`troptoclass[x_ + y_]:=max[x,y]`
`troptoclass[x_ y_]:=x+y` 
`troptoclass[x_^n_Integer]:=n*x`

Here's what happens when I try the operations when it's more than 2 expressions:

[image: tropical addition of multiple terms]

or:

[image]

I think it boils down to having Mathematica be able to perform multiple operations in one statement, and also recognition. Is what I'm trying to do here possible in Mathematica? I'm a beginner with this program, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The simplest way is to do something like `a + b c /. {Plus -> Max, Times -> Plus}`; you would need to treat `Power` separately for a general (tropical) polynomial.

Comment: @J.M. thanks! I just asked, what does the /. mean in the code? I'm getting ready to try it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you want to replace Addition by "Max" and Multiplication by addition. It is not clear how a negative term should be treated. For the time being I assume that it will be included in a factor.

Toward this aim, we define following rules:

```
Plus -> Max
Times -> Plus
```

In addition we need a rule for powers:

```
Power[x1_, x2_] -> Sum[x1, x2]
```

All together:

```
rules = { Plus -> Max, Times -> Plus, Power[x1_, x2_] -> Sum[x1, x2]};
```

Now we can give an example:

```
x + y + 2 x y + x^4 /. rules
(* Max[x, 4 x, y, 2 + x + y] *)
```

Comment: Thank you and @J.M. for such a quick response! What does the /. mean exactly?

Comment: You might want to use a more restrictive pattern for `Power`, e.g. `Power[a_, n_Integer?Positive]`.

Comment: @king, anytime you encounter an unfamiliar symbol on the front end (in this case, `/.`), highlight it and press F1 to see more detail about it.

Comment: Great, I'll keep that in mind. And this method worked like a charm! Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but it seems you would just need to replace your x_ with x__

```
f[x__] := Total[{x}]
f[a, b, c, d, e]
(*a + b + c + d + e*)

f2[x__] := x /. Times -> Plus
f2[a b c]
(*a + b + c*)
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. Daniel beat ya to it :P